# jQuery Font Size Changer Not working as Desired

Tags: javascript, jquery, fonts

I'm trying to implement this JQuery Font Size Changer from:

http://simplersolutions.biz/font-resizer

To my website. I got it working with one problem. I need it to stop increasing when the font is 20px. The script allows overides.

I've added:

```
//bind increases
 $('.' + opts.defaultIncreaseClass).click( function() {
    $.fn.fontResize.reSize(true, '20px');
    return false;
    });
// bind decreases
    $('.' + opts.defaultDecreaseClass).click( function() {
     $.fn.fontResize.reSize(false,'10px');
    return false;
    });
```

In the above example, The Bind Decrease works but and stops font from going below 10px but the bind increase doesn't work.

This is the original function we are overriding:

```
 // bind increases
            $('.' + opts.defaultIncreaseClass).click( function() {
                $.fn.fontResize.reSize(true);
                return false;
            });

 // bind decreases
            $('.' + opts.defaultDecreaseClass).click( function() {
                $.fn.fontResize.reSize(false);
                return false;
            });
```

Anyone know why the override is missing? The link mentioned has information on the code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You've changed the spelling from "Resize" to "reSize".

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes everybody but it looks like the question was edited :-)  Typos in code samples are a real drag.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I have not edited the question? Where is the typo exactly? Thanks.